# Solving $(1-x)^3 = -1$ over the complex field

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

> What are the solutions of: $(1-x)^3 = -1$ over $\mathbb{C}$?

We have one real solution which is $2$ so there are two complex solutions.

Comment: Since you have one root, you can divide by $(1-x)^3+1$ by $(x-2)$ and solve the quadratic.

Comment: Do you want a solution in the form of $a + ib$? Can you guess the solutions for $z^3 = -1$ by geometric interpretation?

Comment: @Integrator, I unchecked amWhy answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the fact that $a^3 + 1 = (a+1)(a^2 - a +1)$, we have $$(1-x)^3 + 1 = 0 \iff \Big((1-x)+1\Big)\Big((1-x)^2 - (1-x) + 1\Big) = (2 - x)(x^2 - x + 1)\\ \implies x = 2\, \text{ or }\, x^2 - x + 1 = 0$$

Use the quadratic formula on the remaining quadratic to solve for the remaining two roots.

Comment: How did you think about the first equation?

Comment: I just happened to notice that $(1-x^3) = -1\implies (1-x^3) + 1 = 0$ and so we had a "sum of cubes."

Comment: I used the quadratic formula and got: $x = \frac{1 \pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Wolframalpha says something different. Can you tell me why?

Comment: Your answer is correct. When I checked Wolfram's step-by-step solution, they conclude the same.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Euler Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula)

> $$ e^{i(2k+1)\pi}=-1+i0$$

$$(1-z)^3 = -1=e^{i(2k+1)\pi}$$
where $k\in \mathbb Z$

$$\begin{align}(1-z) &= \left(e^{i(2k+1)\pi}\right)^{1/3}\\
&= e^{i\pi/3},e^{3i\pi/3},e^{5i\pi/3}\\
\end{align}$$
So We have

> $$\begin{align}z &= 1-e^{3i\pi/3}=2\\
> z &= 1-e^{i\pi/3}=\frac {1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
> z &= 1-e^{5i\pi/3}=\frac {1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
> \end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you, but that's an overhead for me, although we've learned this before

Comment: I think you want $(1\pm i\sqrt 3)/2$